# Comparing values in the indices of two dataframes in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, timestamp

I am trying to compare in which index does the timedelta value in one dataframe1 is equal to the timedelta value in another dataframe2 and then trim the dataframe that has more values to make them both start at the same time:

Dataset1:

```
    TimeStamp            Col1  ...  Col2500
    0 days  10:37:34     346   ...  635
    0 days  10:38:34     124   ...  546
    0 days  10:39:34     346   ...  745
```

Dataset2:

```
    TimeStamp          Col1  ...  Col50
    0 days  10:25:20   123   ...   789
    0 days  10:25:45   183   ...   787
    ...
    ...
    0 days  10:37:40   223   ...   789

    for i in df2.index:
            if str(df1.index[0])[7:12] == str(df2.index[i])[7:12]:
                index_value = i
                break
     df2 = df2.drop(df2.index[[0,i-1]])
```

Expected output will be Dataset2 starting at the same time (nearest to the minute) with Dataset1

Comment: `df2[df1.index]`?

Comment: Use pandas datetime and time delta to find which date is closest to the corresponding date in the other dataframe

Comment: @YaleNewman Can you please elaborate a little on how to check the closest time if it isn't exact. I am sorry, I am just starting to learn pandas

Comment: if you can post some lines of code that will produce a dataframe similar to your sample set, i'd be happy to produce a solution for you. to do this you can do df.head(10).to_json(). then, copy paste that json into a variable called data. then you can run pd.DataFrame(data=data). so long as 10 rows is enough across both data-sets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`searchsorted`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.searchsorted.html) for indices for first higher value in `df2.index` like first value of `df1.index`. Then select second `df2` by positions by [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
#necessary both indices are sorted
df1 = df1.sort_index()
df2 = df2.sort_index()

a = df2.index.searchsorted(df1.index[0])
print (a)
2

df2 = df2.iloc[a:]
print (df2)
           Col1  ...  Col50
TimeStamp                  
10:37:40    223  ...    789
```

Comment: I thought abt searchsorted there you come

Comment: Thanks a lot! That worked but it is also making the df have two columns of TimeStamp for some reason :\ Any idea why?

Comment: Is  TimeStamp not the index ?

Comment: `iloc` function created new column? I never seen it before. what is `print (df2.info())` ?

Comment: Or simplier what is `print (df1.index)` and `print (df2.index)` ? Is `TimedeltaIndex` in both indexes?

Comment: `Timestamp` is column ( check it by `print (df1.columns.tolist())` and `print (df2.columns.tolist())` ) then need `df2 = df2.set_index('TimeStamp')`

Comment: Nevermind, sorry about that...it was doing that from before. I have: 
   df2.set_index(pd.to_timedelta(df2['TimeStamp]), inplace = True)

Comment: I have inplace = True , no idea why it is still doing it!

Comment: Maybe need only `df2.index = pd.to_timedelta(df2.index)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155703/discussion-between-jezrael-and-brain-overflowed).